# MongoDB C# Aggregation - unwind -> groupBy

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have object Order with OrderItems.
I need grouped the data by field ProductId (in orderItems) and show sum for each product. 
This solution works well:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Order>("Order");
var result = collection.Aggregate().Unwind(x=>x.OrderItems)
.Group(new BsonDocument
                {
                            {"_id", "$OrderItems.ProductId"},
                            {"suma", new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "$sum" , "$OrderItems.UnitPriceExclTax"}
                                }
                            }
                }).ToListAsync().Result;
```

But I don't want use pipeline, I need prepare full sample in c#.
And this solution doesn't work.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Order>("Order");
var result = collection.Aggregate()
.Unwind(x=>x.OrderItems)
.Group(i => i.ProductId, g => new { ProductId = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(i.UnitPriceExclTax) })
```

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 3):

I found solution,
I've prepared extra class:

```
        [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
        public class UnwindedOrderItem
        {
            public OrderItem OrderItems { get; set; }
        }

        var agg = database.GetCollection<Order>("Order")
                .Aggregate()
                .Unwind<Order, UnwindedOrderItem>(x => x.OrderItems)
                .Group(x=>x.OrderItems.ProductId, g => new
                {
                    Id = g.Key,
                    Suma = g.Sum(x=>x.OrderItems.PriceExclTax)
                })
                .ToListAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you're trying to use `linq` syntax instead of `mongodb`. I don't know of any solution that would allow similar syntax to what you've described above in the `aggregation-pipeline`.

Comment: is this true in 2.2?